# Python pyqt database query on a qlist

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

If you please can help me, I would appreciate it

I'm doing a query of sqlite3 and I want to show the result on a QListWidget

```
for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM typem WHERE Type LIKE ?",('%'+'b'+'%',)):
     test = ''
     test += str(row[1])
     print test
     self.listWidget.addItems(test)
```

On the "print teste" is showing this

[image: On the "print teste" is showing this]

And on the "addItems" saves like this

[image: And on the "addItems" saves like this]

Can you please help me? 
Thanks

Comment: Change `self.listWidget.addItems(test)` to `self.listWidget.addItem(test)`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks once more! :)

Comment: Yes ofc :) In five minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `addItems()` method the `QListWidget` class assumes that you are passing an iterable so you get each element, and a string is an iterable, so you get that behavior. The solution in your case is to change `addItems()` to `addItem()`.

Comment: Hi mate, I'm sorry for bothering you again, it is possible to add you in some place to ask you a question? It's not to see any code of anything